# How to limit column widths when using repeat(autofill)

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to create a grid with items stretching from 200 to 250px. My first thought was to use `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 250px));` but columns never shrink below 250px then:

https://codepen.io/hypnos_phi/pen/XONoPL

Ideally, I want the behavior of `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));` but with upper limit of 250px. Setting `max-width` on children helps in a way, but it adds undesireable large gaps when 1fr > 250px:

https://codepen.io/hypnos_phi/pen/LqbMvN

[image]